# How can I access html5 geolocation data in Rails so that I can use it in Geocoder Gem?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails-4, geolocation, jquery-cookie, rails-geocoder

I'm using a jquery cookie to store html5 geolocation longitude and latitude data as I want the user IP address to be accurate.  How would I then access this cookie to use with Geocoder?